# Azure app service not pulling latest image from docker registry

Tags: azure

I have a pipeline that publishes to my private Azure container registry but if I push a new image tagged with `latest`, my Azure app service does not pull the newly tagged `latest` image. I have `Continuous deployment` turned on via the `DOCKER_ENABLE_CI` app setting.

Additionally, I'm using a managed identity to authenticate with the ACR. I feel like the CD portion was working when I was using credentials to pull the image but after switching to managed identity it appears to have stopped. In order to get the new image I have to restart the app service which is not idea and makes this CD option useless...

[image]

Comment: Have you given ACR the Pull Permission for your app service? Just curious.

Comment: I'm using Terraform to create my app service. The service principal that runs the infrastructure has ACR pull permission on the ACR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I am an owner of the subscription I have permissions that allow the webhook to get created automatically if I manually set it up in the 'Deployment center' tab. But since my service principal is pretty locked down it doesn't have that same permissions thus the webhook can't get created. Instead I gave my SP explicit access to contribute to that ACR to create the webhook and in my Terraform code I can create the webhook. Credit goes to someone on Github who posted a way to create the service url.

My solution:

```
resource "azurerm_container_registry_webhook" "webhook" {
  count = var.environment != "s" ? 1 : 0

  # No dashes allowed in the name
  name                = "${replace(lower(azurerm_linux_web_app.main[0].name), "/\\W|_|\\s/", "")}webhook"
  resource_group_name = var.acr_resource_group
  location            = var.location
  registry_name       = var.acr_name

  service_uri = "https://${azurerm_linux_web_app.main[0].site_credential[0].name}:${azurerm_linux_web_app.main[0].site_credential[0].password}@${lower(azurerm_linux_web_app.main[0].name)}.scm.azurewebsites.net/docker/hook"
  status      = "enabled"
  scope       = "asdf/asdf:latest"
  actions     = ["push"]
  custom_headers = {
    "Content-Type" = "application/json"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you enable `Continuous deployment,` App Service adds a webhook to your ACR to notify the web apps. The webhook causes your App Service app to restart and run the docker pull to get the updated image.

So, please go to your ACR, and under webhook, please check if there are running webhooks or not, if not you can create a webhook manually and see if the WebApp get the latest image in the following deployment.
[source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-ci-cd-custom-container?tabs=acr&pivots=container-linux#4-enable-cicd)

Comment: There was no webhook created within my ACR. Can you explain a bit more about the App service creating the webhook? I suspect it's a permissions issue and it's silently failing. If I set the deployment center configurations manually then the webhook gets created by I also have Owner permission on the subscription. I'm using Terraform to create the infrastructure with a service principal. Is the service principal responsible for creating the webhook? I've given it "Contributor" role over the ACR and it still doesn't work